# A noun that really does not have a plural

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I recently wrote an answer about the verb agreement when using the word "some", and I needed a noun that didn't have a plural. I had a discussion about this with [David M](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/59527/david-m), that has been moved to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13173/discussion-between-david-m-and-programfox).

But we didn't really find a noun that *absolutely* does not have a plural. Do you know a noun that doesn't have a plural?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Singulars_without_plurals  Does this answer it?

Comment: This really needs some clarification - what *kind* of word?  "**A**" comes to mind, but I suspect it's not what you have in mind - but it's not clear what you DO have in mind.

Comment: I'm looking for a noun.

Comment: OK - a noun, then.  But do you mean "a noun for which the plural and singular are the same", or "a noun representing a concept of which there Can Be Only One"?

Comment: @MT_Head: A noun representing a concept of which there Can Be Only One.

Comment: There's only one Batman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Singulars without plurals**

Mass nouns (or uncountable nouns) do not represent distinct objects, so the singular and plural semantics do not apply in the same way.

Some examples:

Abstract nouns
deceit, information, cunning, and nouns derived from adjectives, such as honesty, wisdom, beauty, intelligence, poverty, stupidity, curiosity, and words ending with "ness", such as goodness, freshness, laziness, and nouns which are homonyms of adjectives with a similar meaning, such as good, bad (can also use goodness and badness), hot, and cold.

In the arts and sciences
chemistry, geometry, surgery, the blues,[1] jazz, rock and roll, impressionism, surrealism. This includes those that look plural but function as grammatically singular in English: mathematics (and in British English the shortened form 'maths'), physics, mechanics, dynamics, statics, thermodynamics, aerodynamics, electronics, hydrodynamics, robotics, acoustics, optics, computer graphics, cryptography, ethics, linguistics, etc.; e.g., Mathematics is fun; Cryptography is the science of codes and ciphers; theromodynamics is the science of heat. Data often functions as a singular in terms such as 'data collection' or 'data processing'.

Chemical elements and other physical entities:
aluminum (US) / aluminium (UK), copper, gold, oxygen, nitrogen, carbon, equipment, furniture, traffic, air and water

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Singulars_without_plurals

Comment: I have some issues with these, in that they don't seem to *quite* meet the OP's requirement: almost all of them actually CAN be converted to plurals.  (Yes, it changes the sense of the word, but...)  For example, "deceit" actually **does** have a plural: "deceits".  Many "-ness" terms can turn into "-nesses"; true, theose are mostly neologisms, but a surprising number of them have "stuck".
So: I think you're on the right track, but you REALLY need to clean up / pare down the list to properly answer the question.

Comment: @MT_Head Yes, I suppose you are right.. But the answer is in there somewhere; and there may be controversy over which neologism are acceptable or not. I would say, one could flippantly pluralise ANYthing.

Comment: Flippantly, yes - but: *deceits* yes, *cunnings* no; *geometries* yes, *jazzes* no (except as a verb...); *carbons* yes; *furnitures* no.  And so forth.

Comment: 'Coppers' (the kitchen utensil) is an antiquity rather than a neologism. 'Furnitures' (Louis XIV and Louis XV, for instance) has also been around for quite some time. One really _has to_ look up each noun in a good dictionary (or better, several) to check for count and non-count senses.